# How do you pass a string parameter in a view to a url?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have a url that takes in any string as a parameter. I would like to pass a parameter inside of a view when I am redirecting to this url. How do you do this in Django?

I have a url defined like this:

```
url(r'^user_view/(?P<service_name>.+)$', views.user_view, name='user_view'),
```

My relevant view code (that is incorrect) looks like this :

```
service = RestaurantService.objects.get(pk=5)
return HttpResponseRedirect('/services/user_view/%s'%service.service_name)
```

Comment: can you post some of your `user_view` view code

Comment: is it possible you have another view also with `name='user_view'`?  I pasted your url conf above into a fresh django project and `redirect('user_view', service_name='Tasty Pizza')` works fine

Comment: It works when I explicitly right out a string, like 'Tasty Pizza', but when I pass a variable like service.service_name, it gives an error. Specifically it never reads service.service_name, even though I can print this string in the console.

Comment: When I try to pass in a variable doesn't contain the parameter and looks like this: www.example.com/services/user_view

Comment: I figured it out. I had an error in user_view. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would use [`redirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect) shortcut, it would automatically reverse resolve the URL for the provided view name and pass the parameters:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    service = RestaurantService.objects.get(pk=5)
    return redirect('user_view', service_name=service.service_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm still getting the same error: user_view() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: I think it's because it's possible for a service to contain spaces in its name?

Comment: @MichaelSmith not sure, try replacing the regexp with `^user_view/(?P<service_name>[\w|\W]+)$`.

Comment: It breaks for example with Services with names like: 'John's Steak House', 'Mike's 21st Century Pub'. When I redirect from an html page like: /services/user_view/{{service.service_name}} I have no problem redirecting and rendering the correct page. A sample service name that renders with your solution is: 'Tasty Pizza'

Comment: Actually I take that back, 'Tasty Pizza' doesn't work either. Sorry for the confusion. Hmm I'll look into this some more.

Comment: this should just work, there shouldn't be any problem with spaces in the name since the `.+` regex will match them. I think the problem lies elsewhere in your django project

Comment: @Anentropic you are correct. Sorry for the confusion. My user_view had a redirect loop..